# how to use ajax auto refresh effectively?

Tags: php, ajax

I am looking to have an auto refresh a la Facebook homepage. I have already implemented the Ajax code but I am wondering what is the best way to go about the refresh.

I can do a setInterval and have it refresh every X minutes, but this seems unnecessary when the site is open in a tab, but not in use.

I can bind it to an event like mouseover (which i tested) but then it refreshes every time the mouse moves over the div, and for the most part is unnecessary. (as well as creating a heavy load on the server.)

I suppose ideal situation would be when there is a mouseover, it checks how long ago it was last updated, and if its been more than X minutes, do a refresh. Which I suppose is a combination of both the above methods.

Is there a way I don't know about? What about some kind of method that is implemented on the page where my div content comes from (my own page located on the same server), that waits for new material then "pushes" it to my div, instead of of my div going and "pulling" the info from the page?

Comment: i think, best way using node.js.

Comment: Are you refreshing the whole page or a certain section? If you're refreshing the whole page, why not use an iframe? Otherwise it makes more sense to add a new div to a pre-existing list of divs

Comment: refreshing my main div, for the main content. I want an ajax refresh to avoid the user having to constantly hit f5 when waiting for new content. An iframe would just as much require a refresh as having it on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does it using a keep-alive connection.

This means, an ajax request is sent to the server with a Keep-Alive header. It will stay alive until new content is available, the server then returns the response and the connection closes. As soon as this happens, a new keep-alive connection will be established etc.

On the PHP side, you can use sleep() in combination with an endless loop to check for new conent.

However, I don't know how much this affects your server's cpu usage...

Comment: wouldnt sleep() keep the page in a constant "loading" state?

Comment: It would for synchronous requests. Asynchronous requests just idle in the background.

Comment: could you explain a little more how I would go about this? I'm not sure I understand your approach.